# Equation for flow out of a container through a vertical slot so the discharge area changes with water height

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, bernoulli-equation

lets say a fish tank leaks along a vertical edge seam. What is the equation for the flow rate as the volume and discharge area changes?